# Import uno ImportError: no module named uno bug

Tags: python, uno

I am new to linux and was wondering how I go about getting the uno python module from openoffice to work within a python script.

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall open office on my machine.
Change the PYTHONPATH variables and nothing appears to be working.

Would someone be willing to give an in depth guide on the step taken to get this to work on a fedora linux machine.

My python script is as follows.

```
import uno

print ("Create Document Script")
```

The following error is returned when the script is run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyCreateDocumentScript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import uno
ImportError: No module named uno
```

Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an error, some code or a traceback to share?

Comment: I've attempted to change the PYTHONPATH but I am very inexperienced with linux. I also tried to move the uno.py files to the python directory but still having no luck

Comment: It looks like the uno module is not in your python path. Did you install uno?

Comment: Yes I did. Managed to fix this and did answer it. Will add the fix here.

To fix locate .bash_profile and add the following
     PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/openoffice.org/basis3.4/program
     export PYTHONPATH
where /opt is the file location of your openoffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you successfully installed python3-uno, I suspect that you were not running your script with python3 but a previous version of python.
To run python scripts with uno for libreoffice you must run your scripts with python3

Answer (score 0):

Python should import uno module so you should import it form openoffice.org package by typing the following command

> /opt/openoffice4/program/python scriptname.py

Then the uno module is imported from openoffice.org(if you dont specify the path it will take the default python without uno module)