# Impossible to import python-uno

Tags: python, linux, libreoffice, linux-mint, uno

My goal is to write a python script that uses LibreOffice to open thousands of xls files and save them as csv files (the files are corrupted, so I need to open them using LibreOffice and then use LibreOffice to save them as csv).

It seems that python uno is the way to do it, but I cannot make it work.
I am using Linux Mint 20.3 (Una), and Python 3.7.4

This is what I did:

Command prompt:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt -y install python3-uno`

```
python3-uno is already the newest version (1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
```

Then I open python and try to import uno:

`python3`

`import uno`

```
>>> import uno
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uno'
```

I have tried every single "solution" I found on the internet, none of which worked.
They included:

Uninstalling Uno and installing again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XD9Of_05lk

Making sure that I am using python3: [Import uno ImportError: no module named uno bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650731/import-uno-importerror-no-module-named-uno-bug)

Trying to install uno with "sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python": https://askubuntu.com/questions/418225/how-do-i-install-the-python-uno-package

The list of things that I tried is too long to fit here.

Comment: Did you try installing it with pip? python3 -m pip install python-uno

Comment: I have. This is the error I get: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-uno (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-uno

Comment: Did you try reinstalling LibreOffice as recommended at https://askubuntu.com/questions/412372/how-to-fix-libreoffice-and-python3-uno? Also probably not the actual problem, but your question says "pyhton3" which won't work of course. Maybe you made a typo of some kind while installing, so double check. Installing `libreoffice-script-provider-python` has always worked for me, although it sounds like you have tried that.

Comment: @JimK Yes, I tried reinstalling libreoffice and then running libreoffice-script-provider-python. Same issue. PS: just fixed the typo on my question, it was only on the question =)

Comment: Check if `uno.py` is in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and `pythonscript.py` is in `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program` or have they been tucked away somewhere else. You can test with `find /usr -name uno.py -print`